# unexpected T_String error and rss

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

I am new to all this and would love to be able to get this to work.

I am trying to create this RSS feed using PHP and Mysql.

I am recieving the following error though:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" - in line 16 which is `<?xml.....`

```
<?php

//setting the variables
$host = '';
$database = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';

//connecting to the database and server
$db_handle = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');

?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
    <title>'.$row['title'].'</title>
    <about>'.$row['about'].'</about>
    <logo>'.$row['logo'].'</logo>
    <website>'.$row['website'].'</website>
    <phone>'.$row['phone'].'</phone>
    <email>'.$row['email'].'</email>
    <facebook>'.$row['facebook'].'</facebook>
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT title, link, description FROM posts");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo '<item>
    <title>'.$row['title'].'</title>
    <about>'.$row['about'].'</about>
    <logo>'.$row['logo'].'</logo>
    <website>'.$row['website'].'</website>
    <phone>'.$row['phone'].'</phone>
    <email>'.$row['email'].'</email>
    <facebook>'.$row['facebook'].'</facebook>
  </item>';
}
echo '
</channel></rss>';
?>
```

i have tried looking but can't see the error.

Answer (score 3):

You have short tags enabled so the `<?` in `<?xml` is causing PHP to interpret it as an opening PHP tag.

To solve this just echo out that line:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is recognizing `<?` as an opening php tag with the `<?xml` causing an issue.

Use 
`<?php echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"; ?>`

Instead of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`